# Laravel Dusk ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED visiting localhost

Tags: laravel, selenium, laravel-dusk, laravel-sail

I have 3 Vuejs SPAs which use the same Laravel API setup using Sail/Selenium/Docker. I want to test each SPA from the API using Dusk but whenever I try to visit localhost with the port (`http://localhost:9007`) I get the following error:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I don't get the error with `http://google.com` or just using relative paths like `/` or `/login`.

Here is the code I am using to test:

```php
$browser->visit('http://127.0.0.1:9007');
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends where the app is hosted and where the test is running.

I assume both are in containers now. Containers connect to each other using their container name as host name. So change `$browser->visit('http://127.0.0.1:9007');` to $browser->visit('http://[target_container_name]:9007');

If you want to connect from inside a container to your host machine you need
`host.docker.internal`.

From container to container it's the container name, e.g. `http://php_container`

From host machine to container, you can just use localhost, as long as you added your port mapping in docker-compose.yml

Comment: One is in a container, the other is a Vuejs app without docker

Comment: In that case your address should be host.docker.internal

Comment: I tried that, doing `http://host.docker.internal` and it said "The hostname is invalid" or something to that extent.

Comment: I will edit my answer to reflect this, however I would be helped if you could specify more verbose what is running in the container and what is not

Comment: @onlineThomas how can i contact you, need to talk you about something

Comment: @SecretKeeper I sent you a message on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233649/room-for-online-thomas-and-mashiro